# Reference errors on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

It's my first time using Visual Studio 2012. I opened a project that was created on a different computer and now I'm receiving errors:

[image]

When trying to add these references most of them didn't exist.

Thanks

Comment: Check the path VS is looking to find these files. It could be a version that isn't installed on your pc or maybe the last developper put these files in a folder that isn't on your pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are as they state: they are not installed, referenced or missing from the project. To resolve this you need to make sure you even have these .dll on your system, if you do then you need to reference them in your project.

1. Right click on your project and then click on "Properties". Then navigate to "References", inside there you should see the references needed for the project. You may have these in there, but the path may be empty. If they are you need to "Remove" them and navigate to the required path to add the correct .dll you are missing.

On another note, I believe the VBIDE error is part of the Microsoft Word Object Library for interacting with Word.

Good Luck!